# Any workaround/Add on for html in case comment section

Tags: case, case-comment

Currently there is no way we can input html, images in case comment section, but is there any add-on/apps available in salesforce to achieve it?

Already this been asked in idea stack exchange : https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWcvUAF/need-html-in-case-comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Data Model for Case Comments does not support a Richtext so this is not possible at this point.

Couple of solutions

1. Roll your own child object to Case called CustomCaseComments and have a Richtext field that can store the HTML and render it.

OR

2. Enable chatter Feed and use chatter for case collaboration.